# How to prevent drawing overlap (eraser) on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Basically I have some movable shapes, and the ability to draw. When a user erases a drawing (drawing white over their drawing), I don't want them to be able to draw over the movable shapes.

Right now the only solution I can think of if to check every-time the eraser moves to see if it is colliding with a shape and just not draw white.

The problems I see with this solution:

1. Having to check every single shape every single time the eraser moves sounds like it will slow things down.
2. When I move the shapes around (and the canvas redraws) the white eraser drawings will appear over the shapes (so that part of the shape appears erased).

Comment: A simpler solution would be using 2 canvas elements, one on top of another. You can use the mousemove event for the top canvas to delete shapes from the canvas below, while keeping your movable shapes on the top canvas. To get more help please  add some code.